# How to make use of "username or Email", to login in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, devise

I found a way to customize devise to use  username to login instead of email address.
But actually I want to use combination :-

```
Enter username or Email:   <text-box>
Enter your password    :   <text-box>
```

So how to achieve this ?

Actually we need to modify devise gem's configuration to support this.
for now I know that modifying the "/config/initializers/devise.rb"  file as

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ] (edited from email to username.)
```

would actually enable logging in using username instead of emailid.
But can I do some thing like:-

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username | :email] in the "config/initializers/devise.rb" file.
```

So that we devise can take username or email as authentication key at runtime depending on the input provided by user.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at there : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address
(url updated)

It explains how to allow users to sign in using their username or email address.

Comment: this works. There are X other identical Q and As out there. I have this working with devise 2.1, Rails 3.2, mongoid 3

Answer (score 3):

how about filtering on the username or email if there is an @ and a . which would be characteristics for an email.

Comment: We do this in our application. Of course it's not the most elegant solution but it couldn't be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this guide https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

but remember to change  :authentication_keys => [:username] at devise model or at devise.rb as suggested by the guide to :authentication_keys => [:login] to make it work

Regards